# How can the extra space above/below HTML5 video in Safari be removed?

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

I'm seeing a strange bug (only) in Safari (recent versions, desktop and mobile) where extra space is added above/below an HTML5 video. That might be okay in some scenarios, but in mine it reveals a background image being used to work around an IE video/poster bug.

[image: Safari Bug]

I'm inclined to believe that this is a Safari bug, as if I toggle various CSS properties within the dev tools or with JavaScript, the problem goes away. The JS approach *could* potentially be a solve, but the user has to suffer through the flash of unstyled content and I'd prefer to work around or correct the issue at the CSS level. (I've tried various workarounds: setting height on video, changing display on video)

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<section class="series" style="display: block;">
  <video autoplay="" class="series-video series-video-desktop" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" poster="data:image/gif,AAAA" src="https://iandevlin.com/examples/speechapi-video/video/big-buck-bunny.mp4"
    style="background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/1024/768);"></video>
</section>
```

... and CSS:

```
section {
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

video {
  background: none no-repeat 50% 50% transparent;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also, FWIW, here's my JS fix:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var xs = document.querySelectorAll('.series');
  [].slice.call(xs).forEach(function (x) {
    // doing this via CSS has no effect
    x.style.setProperty('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j5nkd69/1/)

Comment: Interesting. Is having your background image the same aspect ratio as the video not an option?

Comment: It is and will be in my final product. Unfortunately, the space remains no matter what the size of the background image is and the design requirements call for there to be no space between the top of the video's container and its previous sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue noted above by replacing `width` with `min-width` and `max-width`:

```
video {
  background: none no-repeat 50% 50% transparent;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  /* width: 100%; */
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 999px;
}
```

[image: fixed]

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0v971xqf/)

Comment: interesting fix. Strange behavior from Safari for sure. Trying to think of why it would do that in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, that was a frustrating issue to work around. These sorts of issues are a large part of why I've drifted away from front-end development. I can't believe they're _still_ a common occurrence and that I'm _still_ tearing my hair out over them. (I cut my teeth fixing IE6 bugs ...)